# Java: Can I initialize a function directly without converting it to a variable?

Tags: java, function, variables, methods

For the first code: `findContact(String name)` did not return any contact rather it returned "Error in finding contact".

**First code didn't work**:

```
public Contacts findContact(String name) {
    for (int i = 0; i < contactsArray.size(); i++) {
        if (contactsArray.get(i).getName().equals(name)) {    // USED IT DIRECTLY
            return contactsArray.get(i);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error in finding contact");
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

For the second code: `findContact(String name)` returned contact for the same 'name' inputted for first code.

**Code below worked**:

```
public Contacts findContact(String name) {
    for (int i = 0; i < contactsArray.size(); i++) {
        Contacts contact = contactsArray.get(i);   // ADDED A CONTACTS VARIABLE
        if (contact.getName().equals(name)) {
            return contactsArray.get(i);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error in finding contact");
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: They're equivalent code, so you're wrong. They both work the same. Of course you'd be better off using foreach loop `for(Contacts contact : contactsArray)`. It will print a useless message on each iteration it *doesn't* find the name though, so you should remove the `else` part.

Comment: And of course, the logic is wrong, too. You can't decide that a contact is not in a list before having tested all the contacts of the list. The System.out.println() should disappear, or at least be after the loop. You're confusing "returning" and "printing", BTW.

Comment: You most probably changed the initialization of the list logic, or got them from a database where the order is not guaranteed. So in the second try, you searched with the first item in the list whereas in the first you didn't.

Comment: Point of terminology: the first example **didn't _return_**  "Error in finding contact"; it **returned** `null`, after having **printed** "Error in finding contact".

Answer (score 0):

Both of the code blocks are pretty much the same. According to your logic, if first time, the input item is not matched you reach the else condition which is logically wrong. May be, the input passed each time would have been different. And as some of the members suggested, the logic is wrong.
It is not mandatory to assign to a variable as you have tried in the second block.
But using an **enhanced for loop** makes the code more better.
I suggest the logic to be changes something like the following:

```
public Contacts findContact(String name) {
    for(Contacts contact: contactsArray){
        if(null!=name && name.equals(contact.getName())){
            return contact;
       }
    }
    System.out.println("Error in finding contact");
    return null;
}
```

Comment: @DamilolaOwoyele please accept as answer or up vote. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

use foreach for a clean code

```
public Contacts findContact(String name) {
    if(name != null) {
       for (Contacts contact : contactsArray) {
          if (name.equals(contact.getName())) {
            return contact;
          }
       }
    }
    System.out.println("Error in finding contact:".concat(name));
    return null;
}
```

if you are using java 8

```
public Contacts findContact(String name) {
    Contacts contact = null;
    if(name != null) {
        contact = contactsArray.stream()
          .filter(contactAux -> name.equals(contactAux.getName()))
          .findAny()
          .orElse(null);
    }
    if(contact == null)
        System.out.println("Error in finding contact:".concat(name));
    return contact;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

though I don't really get your intention, slightly modifying the code like below  would help you.

```
    public Contacts findContact(String name) {
        for (int i = 0; i < contactsArray.size(); i++) {
           if (contactsArray.get(i).getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
           /*or below line if you wanted to have a relaxed search
            if(contactsArray.get(i).getName().toLowerCase().contains(name.toLowerCase()))
           */
            return contactsArray.get(i);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Error in finding contact");
        return null;
     }
```